# mysql version error when insert into function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, feed

I'm parsing a feed and I want to insert it into my database.  I echo out the correct feed entries but when I want to insert into database, I get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update, link) VALUES (...) on line 1.

Here's the code:

```
include_once("connect_to_mysql.php");

$xml= simplexml_load_file('http://somefeed/feeds/rss');
$list = $xml->entry;
$title = $list[0]->title;
$img = $list[0]->summary->div->img['src'];
$update = $list[0]->updated;
$link = $list[0]->link['href'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (title, img, update, link) 
VALUES ('$title', '$img', '$update', '$link')") or die (mysql_error());
```

This worked fine throughout my website but now I get this error.  I'm using xampp.  Also some entries are files with http:// that the problem?  I found similar posts but their fixes don't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the are two reserved keywords: `table` and `update` used in your query, it must be escape with backtick.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (title, img, `update`, link) 
VALUES ('$title', '$img', '$update', '$link')
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Still learning, didn't know about the reserved words.  This is parsing a feed so there is no outside data being collected, no input data.  I'll move on to mysqli (maybe PDO) when I feel more comfortable with mysql functions.  Thanks again.

Comment: One more suggestion, next time try **not** to use reserved keywords ;)

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, like I said, I'm still learning. Didn't even know about reserved words.

Comment: @denikov mistakes are your best teacher `:D`